# Toggle Overlays shortcut?

Tags: interface

I used to have a shortcut to toggle 'Display Only' option in 2.7 but in 2.8 that no longer works and I have to click the 'Display Overlays' button manually which is annoying. 
Does anyone know how to setup a keyboard shortcut like that?

Comment: Was just a short-lived bug, it seems. I assigned a hotkey for this via the context (right-click) menu recently. Don't know when the fix came in but it's no later than 6/4/19 (date of my current build).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got it, you need to set up a hotkey manually, this is not accessible from the right-click menu:

- Hit <kbd>F4</kbd> to get to the **Settings Menu** and go to *Keymap*
- Open *3D View > 3D View (Global)*
- Scroll to the bottom and hit the <kbd>+ Add New</kbd> Button, to add a new Key-Binding
- Enter `wm.context_toggle` in the Context Field
- The Context Attribute Field will now appear. Set it to `space_data.overlay.show_overlays`
- Don't forget to **save** your Hotkey Settings

[image: Settings to set up a Custom Hotkey for Overlay Toggle]

Comment: "No module named 'space_data'" error pops up

Comment: While you did not specify what version you are using, in the ones past 2.90, you can just right click the overlay toggle and type in your hotkey directly. If you have already set a custom one up,

Enter wm.context_toggle, Context Attributes: Space_data.overlay.show_overlays and leave Module blank.

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>Alt/Option</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> Works for me in 2.82a, mac version.

Comment: Same for me. Works in 2.83.

Comment: Can confirm that `Alt` + `Shift` + `Z` works for Blender 2.92 on Linux. Usually, the relevant shortcut is shown in the tooltip - odd that this isn't the case for _Display Overlays_.

Comment: @GeorgeHawkins, Thanks, man. Was looking for the shortcut in Linux version here.